# How to responsive the large background image using CSS (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, responsive-design

I have a big background image, but the image is not good in small mobile browser. It displayed a horizontal scroll bar and the image is crop.

The image should be:

- The 3 person in the image should be display in the center
- No scrollbar

How to fix this?

CSS (responsive)

```
.header-home-div{
  background: url(/testEnvironment/files/homepage-header-mobile.jpg) !important;
  height: 700px;
  width: auto;
```

I tried to use this:

```
background-size: cover !important;
background-position: center top;
```

but it's not working

Here's the [link](http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment)

I use [this](http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/) to test the responsiveness of the image

Comment: Use: `width: 100%; height: auto` instead. Also, why the need for `!important`?

Comment: Remove the no-repeat !important from your mobile `background` property. Just do it the same way as you did on desktop, without the use of important and the use of the property `background-repeat: no-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the mobile size, you use an `!important` to the background property. So you need to use `!important` for setting a size too like this :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px)
.header-home-div {
    height: 1500px;
    width: auto;
    background-size: 100% !important;
}
```

It's better to remove the `!important` property at first instead of overwriting it with the above fix by the way.

The horizontal scrollbar depends on `.header-home-h1` margin. The following should fixed it :

```
@media (max-width: 520px)
.header-home-h1 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2.25em;
}
```

Comment: it works but in the 420px size the image is too small. There's a way to stretch the height of the image? so the text will be fit and not overlap?

Comment: You mean 240px size ? You can add a media query to it, something like this : `@media screen and (max-width: 241px)
.header-home-div {
    height: 700px;
    background-size: 100% !important;
    background-position: center center;
}`

Comment: yes, i tried to use @media screen and (max-width: 241px) but the image is not stretch

Comment: You couldn't strech the image on the height and keep the good ratio of seing the 3 people on the pictures, you have to choose in this case I think, between a full covering image where you don't see all of the three people or this

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 241px)` is not working in 240px browser size :( instead it always call the `@media screen and (max-width:420px)`